# Interact Sub Thread with Main Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to Android. I need to split a string and set the text view. I did this but the application stops working.

This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);


    final EditText date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box2);
    final EditText age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box3);
    final Intent result= getIntent();

    String [] parts = result.getStringExtra("string").split(".");
    date.setText(parts[0]);
    date.setText(parts[1]);
    date.setText(parts[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the **String [] parts** has length greater or equal to three to avoid index out bounds exception

Second, you cannot access a View from a background thread, you can use a Handler or an AsyncTask
http://android-pro.blogspot.com.eg/2011/05/threading-in-android-part-1-handlers.html
http://android-pro.blogspot.com.eg/2011/05/difference-between-handler-and.html